# YYYY/MM/DD format - JavaScript Date Validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check whether a date is valid using the following function which I found online (which I changed to my date format):

```
function isValidDate(date)
{
    var matches = /(\d{4})[-\/](\d{2})[-\/](\d{2})/.exec(date);
    if (matches == null) return false;
    var day = matches[2];
    var month = matches[1] - 1;
    var year = matches[3];
    var composedDate = new Date(year, month, day);
    return composedDate.getDate() == day &&
             composedDate.getMonth() == month &&
             composedDate.getFullYear() == year;
}
```

It was for the format MM/DD/YYYY but i tried changing the regex so there was {4}  for the first part (which was {2}) and the last one to {2} which was {4}. Sorry, I don't really know what I'm doing with regex within JavaScript.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/showthread.php?190078-Javascript-Date-(yyyy-mm-dd)-validation

Comment: The number in braces (e.g. `{2}`) represents the number of times the preceding symbol (e.g. `\d`) is to be repeated.  Does this answer your question?

Comment: I think you also need to change around the order of `var day = matches[2];
    var month = matches[1] - 1;
    var year = matches[3];` so that it aligns with your changed-around format.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I found this codecademy course more helpful to learn http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-intermediate-en-NJ7Lr/0/1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also change the order of reading the data:

```
var year = matches[1];
var month = matches[2] - 1;
var day = matches[3];
```

So in case your format is YYYY/MM/DD, the first matched group should be the year, the second the month, and the third the day. This way the function should work.

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4gure/1/)
- [Learn Regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), it is fun! Not as difficult as it seems and is worth it.

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely learn Regex - it seems really useful.